# Is there a way to verify if a SSIS instance was configured as a cluster resource or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We had 2 servers in a cluster ( no aoag ) with SQL + SSIS.

one of the cluster nodes died and we removed it. we are in the plan to create a new cluster node and configure SQL engine normally on it as a cluster resource, BUT we don't remember if the SSIS was also configured as a cluster resource.

since SSIS is not cluster aware, and MS doesn't recommend SSIS being in a cluster resource, what would be the option here? SSIS is just a service that runs packages and I'm confused how can I add a new SQL cluster node together with the SSIS ( the SQL in the new node is easy, the issue is the SISS ).

would it work to install the SSIS in the new cluster node after the sql installation, and point the packages to a shared drive?

Because honestly I'm confused on what would happen if there's a failover to node2 with SSIS only installed on Node1.

thank you.

Comment: Note there's no good reason to use the SSIS service.  Integration Services Catalog and SQL Agent are both cluster aware, and all you need to manage and run SSIS packages.  The SSIS feature just needs to be installed on all cluster nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. I got some reads on this and I got to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] BUT we don't remember if the SSIS was also configured as a cluster resource.

Check the cluster resources, if it's in there (and most likely failed) then it was configured. If there isn't a resource in any of the groups then it wasn't added in as a cluster resource.

> since SSIS is not cluster aware, and MS doesn't recommend SSIS being in a cluster resource, what would be the option here?

Not cluster it as the people who created it have told you. Use it locally, use it on a different server, etc.

> would it work to install the SSIS in the new cluster node after the sql installation, and point the packages to a shared drive?

If you're going to do that, why not just create a *dedicated* host for it and not mess with the clustering items that are clearly complicating things?